# Change text color while typing

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to change text color while typing. I'm coding in VB.NET. I have RichTextBox and I want to change text color. Here is my code in TextChanged event :

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rtbox.TextChanged
    Dim n As Integer = rtbox.SelectionStart 'Store the current position of cursor

    If rtbox.Text.IndexOf("<?php") <> -1 Then
        rtbox.SelectionStart = rtbox.Find("<?php")
        rtbox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
        rtbox.SelectionStart = n
    End If

    If rtbox.Text.IndexOf("html") <> -1 Then
        rtbox.SelectionStart = rtbox.Find("html")
        rtbox.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        rtbox.SelectionStart = n
    End If

End Sub
```

If I type `<?php` it will change the color of

Comment: you might be reinventing the wheel. see [FastColoredTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct way to to highlight syntax because richtext editor is not right choice to use as syntax highlighting. richtext editor is also very slow and thus performance is also slow.

there is already syntax highlighter available you can try this one

https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox

or you can just try this one

https://colorcode.codeplex.com/